# Microsoft Graph Access Token using username and password in Java

Tags: java, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

Can I obtain access token using email and password in java. I saw plenty of examples using .NET library but not anything for java, I have tried the following thing :-

```
private static String getAccess_Token() {
       AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;

        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Authentication_Constants.TENANT + "/oauth2/authorize";
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(url, false, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authContext.acquireToken(Authentication_Constants.RESOURCE, Authentication_Constants.CLIENTID, 
                    Authentication_Constants.EMAIL, Authentication_Constants.Passowrd, null);

            authResult = future.get();
           /* System.out.println("get access token: \n" + authResult.getAccessToken());
            System.out.println("get refresh token: \n" + authResult.getRefreshToken());*/
            return authResult.getAccessToken();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

but its throwing me an exception

```
 com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.
```

Is there any other API which will allow me to do this?

Comment: The whole point of OAuth is that you never have the user's password.

Comment: @SLaks is there any other way through which  i will be able to do it in backend?

Comment: I doubt it.  You should never do that.